# Why does or doesn't COUNT() work with SELECT TOP in MS SQL Serveer?

Tags: sql-server

I have just started learning MS SQL Server and came across a problem to find median value of LAT_N from a DB on HackerRank.
[Here's](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-20/problem?isFullScreen=true) the problem.
[Here's](https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-challenge-images/9336/1449345840-5f0a551030-Station.jpg) the DB schema if aren't able to view the above link without logging in.

Here's my code.

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN COUNT(LAT_N)%2=0 THEN TOP COUNT(LAT_N)/2 LAT_N
    ELSE TOP COUNT(LAT_N)/2+1 LAT_N
END as col1
INTO T1
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LAT_N ASC;

SELECT TOP COUNT(LAT_N)/2 LAT_N AS col2
INTO T2
FROM STATION
ORDER BY LAT_N DESC;

SELECT TOP 1 col1
FROM T1
ORDER BY LAT_N DESC;

SELECT TOP 1 col2
FROM T2
ORDER BY LAT_N ASC;
```

And I got here's the error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server dbrank-tsql, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TOP'.
```

So I decided to try it on a small database on W3schools.
[Here's](https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_top&ss=-1) the editor.

This query works:

```
SELECT TOP 3 *
FROM Customers;
```

But this doesn't:

```
SELECT TOP COUNT(*)/2 * 
FROM Customers;
```

Can someone please explain:

1. Why it doesn't work and
2. How to make TOP COUNT(*)/2 work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Your SQL doesn't make sense. `TOP` needs a scalar value after it, and it's an expression, it need to be in paranthesis (`()`). `SELECT TOP COUNT(*)/2 * ` doesn't make sense, asn you want to `TOP` *what?* Then you have `COUNT(*)/2 *` What are you then multiplying that value by? You're missing part of the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL doesn't make sense. `TOP` needs a scalar value after it, and if it's an expression, it need to be in parenthesis (`()`). `SELECT TOP COUNT(*)/2 *`  doesn't make sense, as you want to `TOP` *what?* Then you have `COUNT(*)/2 *` What are you then multiplying that value by? You're missing part of the expression.

The same is true for `SELECT TOP COUNT(LAT_N)/2 LAT_N AS col2`. The `TOP` *what*? You're missing a value for your `TOP` and then go straight to asking for a `COUNT` of the non-`NULL` values of `LAT_N` divided by 2. It then appears your missing a comma, but considering you are returning a `COUNT` of `LAT_N` it would need to be in your `GROUP BY` so it is unclear what your goal is there.

If you after the top "half" of the table, (from your comment *"How to make TOP COUNT(*)/2 work."*) use `TOP(50 PERCENT)`:

```
SELECT TOP (50 PERCENT)
       *
FROM dbo.CUSTOMERS
ORDER BY ???;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMERS) / 2) *
FROM CUSTOMERS
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Larnu he said I think the best option is to select the TOP X PERCENT and if you've got a column, like created date for eg you can get the most recent 50% rows created:

```
SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT 
       *
FROM 
     CUSTOMERS
ORDER BY 
    CreatedDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TOP` requires two parameters:
PARAMETER 1. how many records,
PARAMETER 2. which columns you want to get.

Here is an example usage of the `TOP` (adapted to your question)

```
SELECT TOP

    /* PARAMETER 1. how many records, in this case half: */
    ((SELECT COUNT(LAT_N) FROM [STATION]) / 2)

    /* PARAMETER 2. which columns you want to get, use star for ALL: */
    * 

FROM [STATION];
```

You can also use calculations for choosing the desired number of records.
Here is an example with `CASE`

```
SELECT TOP (  

    /* PARAMETER 1. how many records, in this case 
    if total number of records in a table is even, then get top half of the rows, 
    otherwise, make it even, then get the top half: */
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(LAT_N) FROM [STATION]) % 2 = 0
            THEN ((SELECT COUNT(LAT_N) FROM [STATION]) )
        ELSE
            ((SELECT COUNT(LAT_N) + 1 FROM [STATION]) / 2)
    END
    )

    /* PARAMETER 2. which columns you want to get, use star for ALL: */
    * 
FROM [STATION];
```